# Keystone.js: Best way to implement models for editing Exam and ExamQuestion

Tags: content-management-system, keystonejs

In Keystone.js it is easy to add a model with 'simple' field, eg.

```
Car:
 - registrationNumber
 - model
 - year
 - isAutomatic
```

For all of those fields a [Edit Car] page will be generated, which will have a 'form' with all the fields.

However, as I am working on an Learning system with Exam/Quiz functionality, I have a need to edit more complicated model - an `Exam` and in particular it's `Questions[]`.

All fields of `Exam` except for `Question` are 'simple' (and can easily be rendered as editable fields on the [Edit Exam] page). But how to provide UI for the sophisticated `Question` model?

```
Exam:
  - name
  - durationMinutes
  - welcomeText
  - Questions[]
```

The the main purpose of UI is to edit `Questions` in the context of an `Exam` (as each exam can have up to 100 of questions).

```
Question:
 - questionType:single_choice|mutliple_choice|picture|text|longtext)
 - questionText
 - questionChoices[] : string
 - correctAnswer: string
 - explanationTextLong: string
```

I wonder best way to add this related list `Questions` editor to the keystone UI?

Comment: I am working on similar solution of learning system, 
you may want to split your editing experience into two, just like keystonejs v4, you can create a page which will have all the Exam and have list of questions for this as list. when you want to add more question, you can open a dialog for filling the form.

Comment: @GautamSingh thank you for suggestion! I was considering adding [[Question editor]] modal with form, but adding modals seems to be a 'unversal hack' to UI... so I was wondering if a more elegant solution is available...

Comment: You can either keep the list of question id with exams or have reverse mapping inside questions. Keeping it with question makes more sense as there may not be many items in array as opposed to number of questions in each exam.